# android parsing xml content from String

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Following is the xml content which i get after decrypting an encrypted value

```
<card order_no="1" id="cmpe0rhm3ym5ha8wlqp4jt7u" place="HOME">33</card>
```

Now i have the above content in a String called message.

Now i want parse the values such as id and place using the main tag "card" and the number 
"33" also to be parsed.

Following is what i have been tried

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
                    XmlPullParser cardParser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    cardParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

                    Map<String, String> attrs = XMLParsers.getAttributes(cardParser);
                    String cardTag = cardParser.getName();
                    if (cardTag.equalsIgnoreCase("card")) 
                    {
                        CardTag card = new CardTag();                       
                        card.setId(attrs.get("id"));
                        card.setPlace(attrs.get("place"));
                        card.setCardNumericValue(cardParser.getText());
                        return card;
                    }
```

I have stored the string in an InputStream and again tried to parse it, but i am getting a null pointer exception

Value of String cardTag seems to be null when i printed it.
NullPointerException rises at if condition "if (cardTag.equalsIgnoreCase("card"))"

How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getName())

> For START_TAG or END_TAG events, the (local) name of the current
>   element is returned when namespaces are enabled. When namespace
>   processing is disabled, the raw name is returned. For ENTITY_REF
>   events, the entity name is returned. **If the current event is not
>   START_TAG, END_TAG, or ENTITY_REF, null is returned**.

So, I believe you current event is START_DOCUMENT and you need call cardParser.next() to get next start tag event. Please take a look on example

```
    public class SimpleXmlPullApp{

     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
         System.out.println("End document");
     }
 }
```

**output**

```
Start document
Start tag foo
Text Hello World!
End tag foo
End document
```